# Певною мірою чи в певній мірі?

Tags: значення-слів

В одній із газетних заміток: «…В певній мірі це залежить від самої людини…» 
   Але на сайті «[Як правильно.нет](https://kak-pravilno.net/pevnoyu-miroyu-chi-v-pevniy-miri-yak-pravilno/)» є таке визначення:

> **Певною мірою** – правильний варіант словосполучення в українській мові. Саме такий варіант використовують для того, щоб передати певний ступінь чогось.
>   *Лізі здалося, що вона певною мірою готова до переїзду.
>
>   Бабуся певною мірою допомогла закінчити ремонт.
>
>   Оксана певною мірою готова до навчання в школі.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Роздуми

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах наводить в одній групі такі словосполучення:

> **в** (**у**) значній (великій, вищій, деякій, певній і т. ін.) мірі
>   **до** деякої (якоїсь, певної і т. ін.) міри
>   значною (великою, якоюсь і т. ін.) мірою

Хоча він не наводить приклади для кожного з цих варіантів, але мені здається малоймовірним, щоб одні прикметники вимагали один спосіб уживання, а інші — інші (у таких схожих випадках). Наводить, наприклад, цитату Михайла Коцюбинського з «в значній мірі»:

> Заробляючи, аби тільки не вмерти з голоду, Франко за цей період **в значній мірі** одірваний був од української літератури, і це для нас велика втрата.

Я можу знайти «в певній мірі» зокрема в дорадянських західноукраїнських виданнях:

> У нас суть муравлі переважно пожиточні, понеже вигубляють всяку шкідну хробачню , а також причиняються **в певній мірі** до удержаня чистоти в воздусі, спрятаючи падаль менших животних. <sub>//[Іван Верхратський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) у часописі [«Правда: письмо літературно-політичне»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB)), Львів, 1872.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Значно слабші з огляду на сучасні вимоги драматичної штуки, хоч не позбавлені гарних місць є два найновійші твори Франка «Сон Князя Сьвятослава» і «Камяна душа» писані **в певній мірі** під впливом Шекспіра і пригідні радше до читаня як до виставлюваня на сценї. <sub>//[Василь Щурят](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A9%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) у часописі [«Зоря: письмо литературно-наукове для рускихъ родинъ»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F_(%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81)), Львів, 1896.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Через те, малюючи життє східне, він показує його нам крізь призму руську: таким способом ми увесь час почуваємо, що перед нами переходить не просто східне життє, а східне життє, описане щирим Русином, а через те Франків Багдад не є для нас чуже місто, а є **в певній мірі** наше рідне. <sub>//[Агатангел Кримський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%AE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), там же.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Впрочім наведені законні поетанови **в певній мірі** виходять поза обсяг вашого мніня: они бо полагоджують річ остаточно, так що заведенє асекурацийне не може по виплаті домагати ся в судoвiй дорозі звороту асекурацийної суми. <…> Новітне законодавство признає взагалї, що обєктивна міра не всюди при полагодї шкоди находить приміненє; де іменно шкоду спонукала безпосередно або шосередно самоволя (dolus), там належить в рівній мірі відплатити самоволию при вимірі зворотної суми; за самоволю шкідника допускаємо **в певній мірі** самоволю пошкодованого. <sub>//[Станіслав Дністрянський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), «Полагода шкоди з огляду економічного і социяльного», Львів, 1897.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Церков приняла первісно римське понятє заручин яко підготовляючого акту, необовязуючого та зовсїм свобідного; однак невдовзї привязала вона до них релїґійне значінє і в виду сего домагалась для церковних заручин (coram ecclesia) церковного благословеня, щоби сакраментальне значінє вінчаня розвести **в певній мірі** на заручини. <sub>//Він же, «Заручини в австрийськім праві: Габілїтацийний виклад виголошений у Львові дня 26. сїчня 1899», 1899.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Одною з причин такого стану річий, є цілковитий майже брак книжок, що моглиб служити **в певній мірі** «учебниками» соціольоґії - вводити неприготованого читача в великий лабіринт соціольоґічних питань та відповідий, словом, давали можність розглянути ся в предметї. <…> Навпаки, він є **в певній мірі** еклєктик (він сам се розуміє, як показує його замітка про еклєктицизм в соціольоґії), приймаючи крім економічних, ще й другі чинники суспільного житя. <sub>//Часопис [«Молода Україна»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB,_1900)), Львів, 1902.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Християнство було найважнїйшою складовою частиною візантийської культури, **в певній мірі** — і державного укладу Візантиї, тож зближаючись до Візантиї, запозичаючи від неї її інституції, її культуру, було зовсїм природним і льоґічним — приподобитись до неї і в сїм многоважнім моментї, прийняти християнство. <sub>//[Михайло Грушевський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), «Історія України-Руси. Том I. До початку XI віка», 1904.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Коли загальна маса української інтелїґенції була в значній мірі зденаціоналїзована, розуміннє своєї народности можна було знайти лиш у тих, хто близько стояв коло народа, чув в його вустах живу народню мову і **в певній мірі** сам підпадав в своїм побутї впливу народнїх поглядів і оцїнок. <sub>//[Олександр Грушевський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), стаття «Сучасне українське письменство в його типових представниках» у часописі [«Літературно-науковий вістник»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), Львів—Київ, 1908.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Під натиском економичних потреб і тяжкої боротьби з селянством, тоді було «одступлено», як кажуть большевики до «перепочинку»: було дозволено **в певній мірі** приватну торгівлю, дозволено кооперацію, просте обирання селянства замінено продналогом, змінено військовий комунізм, допущено **в певній мірі** приватника й т. п., що відомо під НЕП'ом. <sub>Часопис «Нова Україна», Прага, 1927.</sub>

## Висновки

Позиція деяких джерел (зокрема [«Словник-антисуржик»](http://ukrlife.org/main/prosvita/gn22.htm) Юрія Гнаткевича, [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E/), сайт [«Как правильно»](//kak-pravilno.net/pevnoyu-miroyu-chi-v-pevniy-miri-yak-pravilno/)) щодо суржиковості виразу «в певній мірі» і обов'язкової необхідності заміни його на «певною мірою» здається мені необґрунтованою.

Прийменник «в» цілком підходить слову «міра» (а також прийменник «до» і безприйменниковий варіант з орудним відмінком теж підходять).

Єдине «але»: оскільки в російській мові вживаються аналог українського вислову «в (у) певній мірі» («в определённой степени»), а також (мабуть, рідше) аналог вислову «до певної міри» («до определённой степени»), а аналог вислову «певною мірою» — ні, і при цьому російська мова чинить певний тиск на українську, то, можливо, варто докладати певних зусиль, щоби вживання мовного звороту «**певною мірою**» не зменшувалося під тиском інших (розповсюджених в обох мовах) варіантів (але одне лише це не робить «**в (у) певній мірі**» і «**до певної міри**» неправильними).